# Sort arrays by elements

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have three `String` arrays

```
A: [-22, -3, 2.2, a]
B: [-22, -3, 2.2, b]
C: [-22, 0, 2.2]
```

After sorting I want to get this sequence

```
C: [-22, 0, 2.2]
A: [-22, -3, 2.2, a]
B: [-22, -3, 2.2, b]
```

The comparison between a pair of arrays is done on the first element in the arrays. If the element is identical, the second element, and so on.

What comparator must be used?

Comment: What is the type of these arrays? What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: you want to consider the ascii values of `a` and `b`?

Comment: what are `a` , `b` ?

Comment: to khelwood string array; to WasiAhmad i get first value from A (-22) after i get first value form B (-22), if they are equal -> compare second value from A (-3) with second value from B(-3) and etc.

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi that's all string values

Comment: Amazingly, there is no built-in comparator or function in the Java API to sequentially compare arrays, streams, or iterables. But you can easily write your own.

Comment: @PatrickParker good idea, but my logic is confused :|

Comment: @dmitry_dreko first you need to explain why C is being sorted before A.

Comment: @PatrickParker because second value in C more than second value in A

Comment: you can use radix sort for comparing each array with another , and for comparing in array you can convert all elements to String and the use the Array.sort() method , but i'm curious to know why are you doing this ?

Comment: @dmitry_dreko you said " because second value in C more than second value in A  " which means you want a Descending sort. However, since you have sorted A before B you obviously want an Ascending sort. Which is it!?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct values{
    vector<string> ve;
}array[100];

bool comp(values a, values b){
    if(a.ve.size()<b.ve.size() || a.ve<b.ve)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main(){

    int number, size;
    string str;
    cin>>number; //Number of string arrays
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        cin>>size; // Number of element in each array
        for(int j= 0;j<size;j++){
            cin>>str;
            array[i].ve.push_back(str);
        }

    }
    sort(array, array+number, comp);

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        for(int j= 0;j<array[i].ve.size();j++){
            cout<<array[i].ve[j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3      
4
-22 -3 2.2 a
4
-22 -3 2.2 b
3
-22 0 2.2
```

Output:

```
-22 0 2.2 
-22 -3 2.2 a 
-22 -3 2.2 b
```

Comment: why have you answered a java question with c++ code?

Comment: Ooops i didn't notice java tag.